# How to bypass yii validation?

Tags: yii

I have different role in my project. I want to bypass a validation for user role admin only which is a role in my project. I didn't want to use scenario. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is about Yii2  or Yii1?

Comment: My question is about Yii1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To bypass a validation on saving model, just pass `false` as first argument of `save()` method. It will skip model validation before save.

```
$model->save(Yii::app()->user->isAdmin ? false : true);
```

Comment: `Yii::app()->user->isAdmin` returns boolean, so you can just use `$model->save(Yii::app()->user->isAdmin);`.

Comment: @aslawin you forget to add negation, as TS want to bypass validation for Admin. My syntax is for author just to understand a logic.

Comment: @SiZE, correct, this should be `$model->save(!Yii::app()->user->isAdmin);`. Good point!